# How to open user interface with opening the file

Tags: excel, vba, user-interface

I am using :

```
Private Sub start_Click()
UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```

To open my user interface by pushing the start button. But, I would like my user interface to be opened automatically in the very beginning when I have just opened my excel file. Does anyone know how I can do that?

Comment: put your code into the `Workbook_Open`  sub

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Workbook code pane type this

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a subroutine in your workbook named *Workbook_Open*

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    MsgBox "yo!"
End Sub
```

You can call other functions/subs from here.

Answer (score 0):

The `ThisWorkbook` module is a class module that implements the `WorkbookEvents` interface, which means you get to select what looks like a hidden `Workbook` field in the left code pane dropdown:

[image: Workbook object]

As if `ThisWorkbook` had this code implicitly written for you:

```
Private WithEvents Workbook As Excel.Workbook
```

Selecting `Workbook` from the left dropdown will fill up the right dropdown with all events available in a `Workbook` object:

[image: workbook events]

When you pick an event in there, the VBE generates a stub event handler procedure for you, or navigates to it if it already exists.

Typing the event handler signature by hand will also work, but for the more complex signatures that take parameters of specific types in a specific order, it's simpler to have the VBE generate the stub for you - automatically generated handlers will always have the correct signature!